# Which chapter corresponds to episode 381 of Naruto Shippuden?

Tags: naruto

I want to start reading the Naruto manga, but I would rather start reading from the last episode that was aired (currently episode 381). Do you know which chapter that episode (episode 381) would be?

Comment: I know this isn't related to the current question but if you haven't noticed your [ID Request](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14056/from-which-anime-is-this-pic-from) has been deleted and it seems you forgot something when you made it

Comment: Yeah, I thought I had added the pic but it seems I hadn't, but i don't even remember what pic it was so I'm just going to leave the question deleted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be around **Chapter 646: God tree**.